# How to make a character movable in a local repository?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make my character movable in a spaceship ( that will be playable so in movement ).
Here is the very basic script of my character movements :

[image]

To carry out some tests, I made a platform attached to the spaceship :

[image]

PS : My Player is child of the Spaceship

Comment: I created the environment that you are having right now. I created a capsule that is a child to the moving with constant speed platform and everything seems to work properly. Make sure that your capsule is a child to the correct object or check if you have your script added as a component and if you are not changing values in the inspector. For example speed value to 0

Comment: @SEGMK Yes I agree, but my player has a character controller so he has a rigidbody. So my character isn't attached to the platform. And don't forget that my spaceship will be in movement in all axis

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have the solution to your problem but I have no idea why this works like this. I created everything one more time and this time I put the player inside a room with walls that is moving on a specified path.
Player's class:
[image]
Room's class:
[image]

Hierarchy:

[image]

Player's components:

- CapsuleCollider
- Character Controller
- Rigidbody (you said something about that in the comment so I added it too)

So I got exactly the same problem that you are describing - My room was moving but my player was not (players transform was changing where floor's and wall's was not, maybe that will be some hint for true solution). To fix that I just delete the player (capsule), created it once more, and added to it all the needed components. I also deleted the room and created it once more but I don't think that was the cause.

Comment: Please post your code as *text*, never as images.

Comment: @limserhane I would love to but for some reason, I can not. Stack overflow can not format the code that I'm trying to paste into the answer and I'm hopeless here.